# java mobile application to control pc

Tags: java-me

i am unable to understand the code can anyone help.its a method in a midlet..
which interacts with pc using ip adress and internet connection

```
   private static String[] split(String splitStr, String delimiter) {
   StringBuffer token = new StringBuffer();
 Vector tokens = new Vector();

 char[] chars = splitStr.toCharArray();
 for (int i=0; i < chars.length; i++) {
     if (delimiter.indexOf(chars[i]) != -1) {

         if (token.length() > 0) {
             tokens.addElement(token.toString());
             token.setLength(0);
         }
     } else {
         token.append(chars[i]);
     }
 }

 if (token.length() > 0) {
     tokens.addElement(token.toString());
 }

 String[] splitArray = new String[tokens.size()];
 for (int i=0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
     splitArray[i] = (String) tokens.elementAt(i);
 }
 return splitArray;
}
```

Comment: Just stepover through it .

Comment: What part of the code don't you understand? Did you just post a random code fragment and want us to explain it?

Comment: char[] chars = splitStr.toCharArray();
what is stored in chars after this statement because we havnt initialized splitStr..?

Comment: Mehroz irshad.First you work on this code with some input and analyze what output comes.Then you ask about it.Im expecting this output but comes this .So all of them will help you.But if does not try anything and ask simply means no one help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just iterates over the first argument (splitStr) and splits it up based on the delimiter (2nd argument). It does this by putting all the individual tokens into that vector called 'tokens'.
In the last few lines, it bascially all elements of the vector are put into an array which is then returned.

Comment: Yes, but we have to consider the context.  There's a String.split() out of the box for *modern* Java *SE* but there did not appear to be one when I looked at the *earliest* Java *ME* spec I could quickly find.

Comment: Very well possible. Thanks for the hint.